# How to click the download button in a website and download the xlsx in python

Tags: selenium

I am trying to download the xlsx file from following website: https://upx.world/bigdata
And I want click [the arrow on the lower right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSLts.png)

Here is my code (modified from the internet but doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/xxx/data')
driver.get('https://upx.world/bigdata') 
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]')
btn.click()
```

The error is:
`WebDriverException: Message: 'VirtualEnvironments' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving that because you didnt specify the location of the chromedriver properly. You'll need to point it out exactly to the chromedriver. Also, try to avoid that type of xpath since the page can change and it wont work after that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://upx.world/bigdata-transactions') 


def select_city(city_name):
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.v-select__selections")[0].click()
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='v-list-item__title'][text()='{city_name}']")[0].click()
    sleep(1)


def select_neighborhood(neighborhood_name):
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.v-select__selections")[1].click()
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-49").send_keys(f"{neighborhood_name}" + Keys.ENTER)
    sleep(2)

select_city('Oakland & Piedmont')
select_neighborhood('Fairfax, Oakland')


btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'ma-2')]/span/i[contains(@class,'download')]")))

btn.click()
```

Comment: Problem solved and thank you so much! Just a small follow-up question: Is there a way to automatically close the website that is opened during download

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot close the browser while a download is in pending without stopping the downoad, not even on the "Normal" chrome. What you can do is maybe wait 2-5 seconds and then close it?

Comment: Got it! So I'd better manually close the website after the download finished. May I ask the last followup question? Still in that website (https://upx.world/bigdata-transactions?city=7&actionType=buy), how do I download data in a specific city and neighborhood?

Comment: You can have 2 methods and pass the city and neighborhood name. I'll edit the above code.

Comment: Thank you so much! But when I run your code, I got an index error: ```
IndexError 
<ipython-input-11-df62e7f3805f> in select_city(city_name)
      9     driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.v-select__selections")[0].click()
     10     time.sleep(1)
---> 11     driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='v-list-item__title'][text()='{city_name}']")[0].click()
     12     time.sleep(1)
     13 
IndexError: list index out of range
 ```

Comment: Ow, the site received some changes.  neighborhood id is now: input-49 Oakland became Oakland & Piedmont and "Fairfax" is now "Fairfax, Oakland." Updated the above code